# Why am I getting invalid identifier when executing this SQL?

Tags: oracle, ora-00904

Why am I getting invalid identifier when executing this SQL? I'm completely stumped. What could be wrong with this simple code. The error I get is

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

```
CREATE TABLE themepark
(
apples NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
bananas VARCHAR2(20), NOT NULL,
cherries VARCHAR2(10), NOT NULL,
eggs VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm using Oracle DB for the ones using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

On the flip side, the code below works.

```
CREATE TABLE ticket
(
red1 VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY,
orange NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
yellow NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,
green VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
blue VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
);
```

What makes the 1st code (that doesn't work), any different than the 2nd code that does?

Comment: You don't want a comma after `varchar2(<<n>>)` and before `NOT NULL` in your definition of either the `bananas` or the `cherries` columns.

Comment: Working example taking @JustinCave's advice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27e0c7

Comment: I get it now, thank you, but should I delete this question, as I doubt it would be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

You have commas in your script.

```
CREATE TABLE themepark
(
apples NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
bananas VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
cherries VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
eggs VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```